# 2008R2 SQL Server - Running totals to a certain max?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I got the running total coded however let's say there is a deductible of $500 yet the running total goes up to $1000...How do I code where it stops at $500 and leave the rest as blank? I tried using the case when statement but I couldn't get the result I need...

```
;With RunTot as 
    (Select Distinct 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by memberid Order by OriginalSubmitDate,OriginalSubmitTime) as Row,
        MemberID,
        Convert(varchar(12),
        OriginalSubmitDate,101) as 'OriginalSubmitDate',
        Convert(varchar,OriginalSubmitTime,108) as 'OriginalSubmitTime',
        TotalDrugCostonClaim,
        CPPOnClaim 
    from dbo.Holly_QICRestack_Modified 
    Where ClaimStatus <> 'X' and MemberID = '01317453701') 

SELECT 
    ROW, 
    MemberID, 
    OriginalSubmitDate, 
    OriginalSubmitTime, 
    TotalDrugCostOnClaim, 
    (SELECT Sum(TotalDrugCostOnClaim) 
     FROM RunTot b 
     WHERE b.memberid = a.memberID AND b.row <= a.row) AS CorrectDrugSpend, 
    CPPOnClaim, 
    (SELECT Sum(CPPOnClaim) 
     FROM RunTot b 
     WHERE b.memberid = a.memberID AND b.row <= a.row) AS CPPRunTotal 
from RunTot a
```

Sample below from Excel spreadsheet:

```
CHARGE     DEDUCTIBLE       

14.99      14.99            
421.07     421.07       
94.00      63.94        
210.00     0.00         
3.70       0.00
```

Comment: Please post the entire query, and sample data.

Comment: I had to simplify the code as it was LONG...so here you go :) Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the entire query, but your sample data doesn't contain all of the columns from your query.

Comment: Use CPPRunTotal column - sorry about that....Just show me how...that's all I am asking.

Comment: No worries. We need a sample dataset from dbo.Holly_QICRestack_Modified

Comment: How do I do that? I have a snapshot of the dataset but this stackoverflow new formatting policy is making it challenging :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135997/discussion-between-holly-cathcart-and-scsimon).